# Moving a SurfaceView creates artefacts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm playing a video in a [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and moving it around the screen by changing it's `LayoutParams`. This is working except that moving the view very fast creates a kind of black edges behind it.

I am suspecting that this is due to the fact that the SurfaceView window is positioned during the `layout` pass while the hole is drawn asynchronously during the `draw` pass.

Any workaround for that or at least a way to minimize this effect ? I do not want to use a [TextureView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html) as it can significantly impact the battery usage.

Comment: Not very clear yet but the perceived performance is much better by calling SurfaceHolder.setFixedSize()...